# returning a private static variable

Tags: java, methods, constructor, getter

I am having trouble returning my static private variable personCount. This variable simply counts the amount of people i add into my program, in my constructor for Person i set it so every time a person was entered, personCount incremented by 1. I have also created a getPersonCount method which simply returns the int value of personCount.

My problem is that when trying to implement this method in my test file, I am unsure on how to call the method, and get the value of personCount logged to the output.

I'm not sure if i am a million miles away or a small syntax error away, so any help would be much appreciated!

My Person constructor:

```
public Person(String foreName, String surName, int age,
        double height, String gender)
{
    this.foreName = foreName;
    this.surName = surName;
    this.age = age;
    this.height = height;
    this.gender = gender;

    personCount = personCount +1;
}
```

My getPersonCount method:

```
public int getPersonCount()
        {
            return personCount;
        }
```

My attempt to call the method in my test drive:

```
    System.out.println(getPersonCount());
```

Please let me know if any more code is needed.

Comment: I still have no idea what the problem is. Do you get errors? Unexpected output?

Comment: make `getPersonCount()` static then call `Person.getPersonCount()`?

Comment: why is this variable even `static`?

Comment: Given that `getPersonCount` is not `static`, don't you need a reference to `Person` to start with?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @ScaryWombat - Apparently it's used for counting instances of a class.

Comment: @PM77-1 Seems to be in the wrong place then.  I would not say that `personCount` is an attribute of a `Person`

Comment: Why are you making your static variable private? Just make it positive and go `Person.personCount`

Comment: @user3189142 Because he might not want other people to access it or modify, it's about containment

Comment: While it would make a hair more sense to make the getPersonCount method static, it should work just fine as an instance method, provided you have an instance handy.

Comment: You should do `System.out.println(somePersonInstance.getPersonCount());`.  I would imagine that your statement above gave an error message to the effect that `getPersonCount` is not found.

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are correct in that it is static for containment, purposes it was one of the features we had to include in this assignment.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you for your help, that has solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, make your method definition in class Person like:

```
public static int getPersonCount() { //<-- note the static modifier
   return personCount;
}
```

To invoke it:

```
System.out.println(Person.getPersonCount());//<-- use class name, if your using this method outside the class
```

Comment: It is not required that the method be static, so long as there is an instance of Person available to access it.

Comment: @HotLicks is there any preference as to which fix is more efficient? be it making the method static, or invoking it using access from an instance.

Comment: @freshwaterjoe - There's no compelling reason that I can see for making it an instance method, and some good arguments to make it static.  Although, in fact, the instance method may actually be just a teensy bit more efficient (depending on some implementation details in the JVM version being used).

Comment: @HotLicks the only bug i could think that might pop up, would be that of trying to return the personCount whilst there are no instances of Person, i.e. the phonebook is empty. However have decided to stick with the instance method as it works perfectly well for what i need it for. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

```
public static int getPersonCount() { 
   return personCount;
}
```

with the corresponding call:

```
Person.getPersonCount();
```

**OR**:

```
public int getPersonCount() { 
   return personCount;
}
```

and the corresponding call:

```
myPersonInstance.getPersonCount();
```

So in the last case, you deal with a `Person` instance.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int getPersonCount(){
      return personCount;
}
```

Then invoke above method

```
Person.getPersonCount();
```

Comment: I see 1 error in syntax and 1 in implementation logic.

Comment: @PM77-1 r u talking about the answer or the question?

Comment: I mean - in your answer

Comment: @KickButtowski - Sorry. I hate when it happens to me.

Comment: For once, it wouldn't even compile. But it's OK since the *other* answer is correct.

Comment: `static` is all lower case.  But you are very, very wrong to say that you can't access a static variable from a non-static context.

Comment: @sanjayduttindia "You can't access static variable from the non-static context" => it's strictly the reverse ;)  See this: http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2012/02/why-non-static-variable-cannot-be.html